# Exporting Large Google Files Via API

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'd like to know how to perform a large Google Slide export via API. I've followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) and it works fine with small files. If I try it with a large file, it just doesn't work. It is not returning errors or anything. The logic I'm using is the following:

```
<?php session_start();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes    

//INCLUDE PHP CLIENT LIBRARY
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Create client object
$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/main.php');
$client->setAuthConfig("client_secret.json");
$client->addScope(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
$client->setAccessType('offline');

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {  

  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
  $pptFile = fopen("testPresentation.pptx", "w+");
  $fileId = '1fx2uqe96NgsOabAv8S_mItlEbJ_NJSORqPitH55TMc';

  try {

    $file = $service->files->export($fileId,"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", array("alt" => "media"));
    $fileContent = $file->getBody()->getContents();    

    fwrite($outHandle, $fileContent);

  } catch(Exception $e) {

    print $e->getMessage();

  }

  //Close output file handle.
  fclose($outHandle);
  echo "Done.\n"; 

} else {

  if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {

  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

  } else {

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/main.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

  }

}
```

Like I said, it works with small files but not with large ones. One thing I've noticed is that when I do a `var_dump($file);` on the small file, the *'Content-Length'* header has a size of *"30083"*.

If I do the same on the large file, the *'Content-Length'* header has a size of *"0"*. I assume that exporting large files must be done different. I even run into this https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1124 and tried the snippet there but had no success.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot There are no other users. Also, what other code would you need? The one already placed is basically the "entire" script. Like I said, there is no error returned. Please feel free to try the script yourself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think there is a [reported bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761333) regarding exporting file > 5mb. You may want to follow it to be updated regarding any solutions or workaround.